# multi thread functionality of chrome using webworker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-worker, worker

From my application, i need to run a complex function using a ajax request and in mean time a modal div with a spinning image needs to be displayed. I tried using javascript which works fine in mozilla but not in chrome. as a workaround i tried web worker as shown below.

**main.js**

```
this.Calculate=function(ii)
    {         
      worker.postMessage( {'cmd': 'start'});    
        myfun.calcfun(ii)
      worker.postMessage( {'cmd': 'stop'});           
    }
   var worker = new Worker("worker.js");     
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {   
     if(e.data==1 || e.data==0)
      {
       if(e.data==0)
           document.getElementById("divfade").style.display="none";
            else if( e.data==1)
            document.getElementById("divfade").style.display="block";
      }    
    }
```

**worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
debugger
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'start':
      self.postMessage(1);
      break;
    case 'stop':
      self.postMessage(0);
    //  self.close(); // Terminates the worker.
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
  };
}, false);
```

But  worker.postMessage( {'cmd': 'start'});    executed after   myfun.calcfun(ii). so the modal div is displayed after the server execution completed.
Any suggestion to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem is a little bit vague, but it seems to be to make sure that the modal/spinner shows and hides at the right times. Do you actually need a worker for this?

Have you considered using `jQuery.ajax`’s built-in promises?

```
function handler() {
    // Run code to show modal + spinner

    // At the same time, fire away a request to the server:
    var promise = $.ajax({ url: '/url' });

    promise.done(function(data)
    {
        // Response from server was OK, do your thing
    })
    .fail(function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Something went wrong, inform your user
    })
    .always(function()
    {
        // Run code to hide modal + spinner
    });
}
```

And here’s [a very nice video explaining JavaScript’s event loop](http://vimeo.com/96425312), what causes blocking, and what kind of operations are inherently non-blocking (ie. that don’t really need a worker to run on a thread of its own).